# Convert float to little endian in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm processing data from a socket and successfully converting the data to Int and Floats with:

```
let float = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } as Float
```

Everything was working fine until one iPhone 6 Plus seemed to be using Big Endian for the data.

I was able to convert the Int without much effort with:

```
let uint32 = UInt32(littleEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
let int = Int(uint32)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out how to convert the float data.

Comment: Perhaps one of the `NSSwap*Float*` functions will help.

Comment: All current iOS platforms are little endian, so `UInt32(littleEndian:)` would not change anything. Perhaps you meant `UInt32(bigEndian:)` to convert the number from network to host byte order?

Comment: Martin R. We were testing 4 iOS devices and the simulator. The iPhone 6 Plus had different values. When we converted using the code I posted above, the values matched. Why else would that be?

Comment: I am fairly sure that even the iPhone 6 Plus uses a little-endian architecture. How is the data created? How is it sent? What data do you receive (use `print(data as NSData)` for debugging), and what floating point value do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to read the data into a 32-bit integer first, convert the
endianness, and finally create the floating point number with the 
same bit pattern:

```
let uint32 = UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
let float = Float(bitPattern: uint32)
```

Example:

```
// IEEE-754 big-endian representation of 1.5:
let data = Data(bytes: [0x3f, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00])
print(data as NSData)

let uint32 = UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
let float = Float(bitPattern: uint32)

print(float) // 1.5
```